# Возможно ли сделать пользовательский хук, возвращающий компонент и функцию управления локальным состоянием компонента

Tags: reactjs

Необходимо сделать что-то наподобие пользовательского хука(если подобное возможно), который возвращает массив, содержащий компонент модального окна и функцию, при вызове которой меняется режим отображения окна.

Пример логики представлен ниже, однако он абсолютно нерабочий, т.к. useEffect не может отслеживать изменение переменной замыкания.

Я бы хотел узнать, возможно ли сделать что-то похожее, чтобы можно было не нагромождать компонент, содержащий модальное окно, кучей  ненужной логики. При этом загромождение rudux-хранилища ненужными локальными состояниями тоже является неприемлемым.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import LoginForm from "../LoginForm";
import { Modal } from "antd";

export default () => {

    let isVisible = true;

    const toggleVisibleMode = () => {
        isVisible = !isVisible;
    }

    const LoginModal = () => {

        const [isLoginVisible, setLoginVisible] = useState();

        useEffect(() => {
            setLoginVisible(isVisible);
        }, [isVisible]);

        return (
            <Modal
                centered={true}
                title={'Login'}
                visible={isLoginVisible}
                onCancel={() => setLoginVisible(false)}
                footer={null}
            >
                <LoginForm />
            </Modal>
        );
    }


    return [
        LoginModal,
        toggleVisibleMode
    ];
}
```

Comment: Опишите какой ожидаемый результат вы хотите получить, что должно происходить. Для отображения модального окна достаточно 1 хука `useState`: `const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = React.useState(false)`

Comment: Мне нужен хук, если таков возможен, который возвращает массив с компонентом и функцией, при вызове которой происходит смена isModalOpen на !isModalOpen модального окна, т.е. меняется режим отображение с невидимого на видимый. Суть в том, чтобы я смог вызвать этот хук в любом другом компоненте и получить компонент модального окна и функцию для управления отображением. Я понимаю, как это можно сделать без такого "извращения", однако интересно было бы узнать, возможно ли как-то организовать данный вариант.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Храните состояние, функции и сам компонент модального окна прямо внутри вашего кастомного хука. А из него уже возвращайте все, что необходимо.
Обратите внимание, что видимость модалки должна быть привязана к стейту.

````
export const useModal = () => {
  const [isLoginVisible, setLoginVisible] = useState(false);

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setLoginVisible(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setLoginVisible(false);
  };

  const CustomModal = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Modal
          centered={true}
          title={"Login"}
          visible={isLoginVisible}
          onCancel={handleClose}
          footer={null}
        >
          <LoginForm />
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return {
    modalComponent: CustomModal,
    modalClose: handleClose,
    modalOpen: handleOpen
  };
};```
````

Comment: Благодарю, за ответ. Действительно, что-то я намудрил, а все оказалось на поверхности. Однако этот хук не хочет слаженно работать с анимацией ant design: при развертывании модалки она начинает увеличиваться от элемента на котором и стоит сам onClick с modalOpen, однако анимация свертывания просто отсутствует, хотя должна быть. При инициализации состояния и обработчиков в самом компоненте, где я использую хук, всё работает верно. Может вы работали с ant design и можете предположить в чем кроется быть проблема?

Comment: Вероятно библиотека берет из объекта event положение курсора при клике до развертывания модалки, что обеспечивает свёртывание в ту же область.